# vue config devServer proxy is not working in development mode

Tags: vue.js, production

i have added devServer proxy target as

```
devServer: {
   proxy: {
     '^/': {
       target: 'https://xmlpi-ea.dhl.com/',
       ws: true,
       changeOrigin: true
     }
   }
  }
```

but it is not working when i make build with npm run build, is there a workaround for it?

Comment: The dev server in intended only for development mode. `npm run build` doesn't bundle a server into the app. The result of `npm run build` is intended to be served up by your own production server.

Answer (score -1):

This is for PRODUCTION not for development.

```
npm run build
```

If you are using vue-cli, you can spin you development server with
`npm run serve`

Comment: sir my development server is running very good, but i am now asking that how can i follow the proxy in the production build of the vue app?
like what is the method to follow this proxy in the production of vue app.